# Issues with Unity2D Bounds.Contains() and AI Pathfinding

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence

For context, I'm developing a game where the player controls their character and their dog follows them around. Rather than the dog just moving towards the player, I want it to aimlessly walk around within a specific boundary.

There are two boundaries, the "aimless walk" boundary, and the actual path that the player and dog can walk on.

At the moment, I am generating a new Vector2 with random values that are inside the the "aimless walk" boundary and this is stored as the target for the Vector2.MoveTowards function. I then compare this target with the pathway boundary by using bounds.Contains().

The issue I'm having is that the function only returns true and the dog then tries to walk to a point outside of the path and somehow breaks past the path's collider.

This code is in my Follow() method:

```
if (targetFound == false)
    {
        target = stateVariables.GetRandomPointInBounds(followTargetCollider.bounds);
        targetFound = true;
    }

    rb.MovePosition(transform.position, target, stateVariables.montySpeed * Time.deltaTime));
```

This code is in another script that I'm using to calculate all sorts of other variables:

```
public Vector2 GetRandomPointInBounds(Bounds bounds)
{
    desintationReached = false;
    Vector2 location;

    location = new Vector2(
        Random.Range(bounds.min.x, bounds.max.x),
        Random.Range(bounds.min.y, bounds.max.y)
        );

    if (pathwayBounds.bounds.Contains(location))
    {
        Debug.Log("Location Found: " + location);
        return location;
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Invalid Location");
        return GetRandomPointInBounds(bounds); 
    }
}
```

Here's a screenshot of what the colliders/triggers look like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/watGe.png)

Some more context, the "aimless path" boundary needs to be bigger than the path because there are times where the player can walk up and down and needs to allow for the dog to do the same, if that makes sense?

I hope you can help,
Thanks,
Jamie

edit: changed Vector2.MoveTowards to rb.MovePosition

Comment: does your dog have a rigid body?

Comment: Yes he does, would that be causing an issue?

Comment: no, he should do, but you're moving his position not giving him velocity so you teleport him to places and his physics dont get to interact (btw I love your dog hes lovely)

Comment: He is a good boy. I'll give it a go using the velocity. The other issue I'm having is that it never returns "Invalid Location" when it compares the target location with the pathway boundary?

Comment: have you considered doing a boxcast not relying on the bounds to see what the box touches?

Comment: I haven't but not sure how I would work that out. On a side note, after changing to MovePosition, the dog never reaches his exact target and is always a little bit out so it won't ever try and find a new target. 

How does box cast work?

Comment: have a look :P no one seems to check the unity docs and half the time they even have examples https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.BoxCast.html  well moveposition doesnt use velocity, but, do remember his rb position may not be exactly his real position......